# JQuery, AJAX: How can I populate an array with a json return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to following code but only get "undefined" in the alert box.  Anyone know how I can actually populate the array outside of the .ajax?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var reviewArray = new Array();

    getReviews();

    alert(reviewArray[0]);

});

function getReviews()
{

   $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url  : 'reviewbox.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function ( data ) {

    $.each( data.reviews, function( i, itemData ) {
       reviewArray[i] = itemData.review;
    });
    },
    error    : function ( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var err = "An error has occured: " + errorThrown;
        $("body").append(err);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Ajax calls are asynchronous. When `alert` is executed, the array is not filled yet (the Ajax call did not return yet).
2. The array `reviewArray` is not in any (parent) scope of `getReviews` (i.e. not accessible from that function).

Put the `alert` in the callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    getReviews(function(reviewArray) {
         alert(reviewArray[0]);
    }); 
});

function getReviews(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        /*...*/
        success  : function (data) {
            var reviewArray = [];
            $.each( data.reviews, function( i, itemData ) {
               reviewArray[i] = itemData.review;
            });
            callback(reviewArray);
        },
        /*...*/
   });
}
```

If you want to do it with declaring `reviewArray` beforehand, you also have to define `getReviews` in the `ready` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var reviewArray = [];

    getReviews(function() {
         alert(reviewArray[0]);
    });

    function getReviews(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            /*...*/
            success  : function (data) {
                $.each( data.reviews, function( i, itemData ) {
                   reviewArray[i] = itemData.review;
                });
                callback();
            },
            /*...*/
       });
    }
});
```

But this way, the actual flow of your application might be more confusing.

Comment: Thanks very much appreciate the explanation too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    getReviews();

});

function getReviews()
{

    var reviewArray = new Array();

   $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url  : 'reviewbox.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function ( data ) {

    $.each( data.reviews, function( i, itemData ) {
       reviewArray[i] = itemData.review;
    });
    alert(reviewArray[0]);
    },
    error    : function ( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var err = "An error has occured: " + errorThrown;
        $("body").append(err);
        }
    });

}
```